# How to display column header for matrix table in bootstrap for visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, bootstrap

This is my table, it using bootstrap and integrate with salesforce.
View in normal desktop :

[image]

When view in Ipad/Iphone the table will show up like below.The header is not available.I went through Bootstrap sample but there no example for matrix table.My other concern is header FYxxxxQx is generated dynamically.

[image]

This is sample of my code.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
      <!-- render indirect metrics table format -->
      <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!Updated==false}" layout="none" >
        <li class="list-group-item" style="text-align:center;">No Record(s) Found</li>
      </apex:outputPanel>
      <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!isFlag==true}">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <apex:repeat value="{!snapShotFQ}" var="fq" rendered="{!stockCheck}">
              <th class="text-center">FY{!fq}</th>
            </apex:repeat>   
          </tr> 
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td>
              <apex:outputLabel value="Chicken" rendered="{!stockCheck}"/>
            </td> 
            <apex:repeat value="{!mapStock}" var="ssMetrics" rendered="{!stockCheck}">
                <td align="center">
                    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,###,##0.00}">
                      <apex:param value="{!mapStock[ssMetrics].Chicken}" />
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
            </apex:repeat>
          </tr>                   
          <tr>
            <td>
              <apex:outputLabel value="Fish" rendered="{!stockCheck}"/>
            </td> 
            <apex:repeat value="{!mapStock}" var="ssMetrics" rendered="{!stockCheck}">
                <td align="center">
                    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,###,###}">
                      <apex:param value="{!mapStock[ssMetrics].Fish}" />
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
            </apex:repeat>
          </tr>                
          <tr>
            <td>
              <apex:outputLabel value="Meat" rendered="{!stockCheck}"/>
            </td> 
            <apex:repeat value="{!mapStock}" var="ssMetrics" rendered="{!stockCheck}">
                <td align="center">
                    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,###,##0.00}">
                      <apex:param value="{!mapStock[ssMetrics].Meat}" />
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
            </apex:repeat>
          </tr>                    
          <tr>
            <td>
              <apex:outputLabel value="Prawn" rendered="{!stockCheck}"/>
            </td> 
            <apex:repeat value="{!mapStock}" var="ssMetrics" rendered="{!stockCheck}">
                <td align="center">
                    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,###,###}">
                      <apex:param value="{!mapStock[ssMetrics].Prawn}" />
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
            </apex:repeat>
          </tr>                   
          <tr>
            <td>
              <apex:outputLabel value="Squid" rendered="{!stockCheck}"/>
            </td> 
            <apex:repeat value="{!mapStock}" var="ssMetrics" rendered="{!stockCheck}">
                <td align="center">
                    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###.##}">
                      <apex:param value="{!mapStock[ssMetrics].Squid}" />
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
            </apex:repeat>
          </tr>

</table>
```

The output that I wanted whenever it run in mobile is like below.Where the year display to the next of value.

[image]

Not sure I should tag bootstrap or salesforce.I just tag both.Let me know if you have idea.